# Understanding Eclipses' "The resource is not on the build path of a Java project" error message?

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse I often will get this error:

[image]

For example, I tried to use the shortcut to change a method signature: `Alt` + `Shift` + `C` but it gives me that error.

Is this because I may be using a different project? Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring operations, like many other java-specific operations, rely on the ability of the tooling to correctly parse the code in question.  Generally, that means that:

- The code has to be valid enough (syntax and grammar) for the selected element to the correctly parsed.
- The java source file in question needs to be within a java project's source folder.
- The build path must be correct and error free so that referenced classes and packages can be correctly identified.

This message is telling you that one or more of those conditions are not met.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur while debugging.  When Eclipse stops on a breakpoint it will open a new window in the editor, with the execution stopped on the breakpoint.  Some user operations in this debug pane can result in the error you describe.  For example, suppose you select an object variable and press F3 to open the class declaration for that object.  You will get the error message you describe above.

In this case, select the window which has the live edit version of the file you are debugging, then select the object of interest then hit F3.  The class declaration will open in a new window.

Your mileage may vary.